# killBackgroundProcesses no working

Tags: android

First, I found some similar questions on StackOverflow but none of the answers there solves my problem. I also googled it and read all the top 30 results.

So I am writing a Service that will check what is running in foreground every, say, 20 seconds. If the foreground application is on a blacklist, then I will popup a dialog Activity to say that "the current application needs to be stopped", then when user press OK of that dialog, that application will be stopped via the following method:

```
private void killApp(String packageName) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to kill app " + packageName);
    am.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);
}
```

However, the application is not stopped at all in my test. When the dialog is closed, the foreground app is still there, exactly the same state as it was before the dialog popped up. I believe I have the right API level as well as necessary permissions:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

I am really stuck, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any luck?
you might also want to check this...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195167/automate-closing-of-applications-in-android

Comment: @Campiador No luck. It seems that nowadays you simply can't do things like that on android system.

Answer (score 6):

/*Android will not kill the app or process when it is displaying on screen i.e active view.
so switch to home screen and then kill the app or process you want*/

```
    public void KillApplication(String KillPackage)
{
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);    

    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    this.startActivity(startMain);



    am.killBackgroundProcesses(KillPackage);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Process Killed : " + KillPackage  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();       
}
```

Comment: This is not working in my case. It is not killing background application which I provided via package name

Comment: Does not work for me. I m trying to kill my own processes

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following:

First, add `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` inside the `manifest` tag in `AnfroidManifest.xml`, your manifest file should look like this now:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapplication"
android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
...
```

Second, claim `FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES` permission. This step makes your manifest file look like:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_STOP_PACKAGES" />
...
```

Third, for packages you wanna stop, do:

```
final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.forceStopPackage(PACKAGE_NAME);
```

Just replace `PACKAGE_NAME` with your package name.

If you use Eclipse, just ignore any lint error in `Preferences > Android > Lint Error Checking`.

You need to put the apk in the system directory to gain appropriate permission.

Comment: you will have to sign your apk as system app -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635101/how-to-sign-android-app-with-system-signature

Answer (score 1):

Starting in **Android 14**, when your app calls `killBackgroundProcesses()`, the API can kill only the background processes of your own app.

If you pass in the package name of another app, this method has no effect on that app's background processes, and the following message appears in Logcat:

```
Invalid packageName: com.example.anotherapp
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make your app have the system privilege,that is system app,or you can root your phone so that your app can kill other app as root user.