# Can we close/terminate another app with our app?

Tags: android, foreground-service, device-admin, background-foreground

I have an app in which i have a `device admin permission` and `foreground service`.

Now i want to `close/terminate particular app` when that comes on foreground. I know the package name of that another app.

Let say when i open `chrome (com.android.chrome)`. Now when it comes in foreground i want to close/terminate that app and also remove from the recent item.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You might want to check these links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036895/kill-another-application-on-android
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604097/killbackgroundprocesses-no-working

Comment: Killing the app should be relatively simple, knowing when the app opens is a little trickier. Can your app by an accessibility service?

Comment: Yes my app uses accessibility service.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running as an accessibility service you should be able to detect any event from the app and then ensure it is killed. One way is to use the activity manager:

```
class AccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
    override fun onInterrupt() {
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        if (event?.packageName == "com.whatever.app") {
            val am = applicationContext.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            am.killBackgroundProcesses(event?.packageName)
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe just using an execution:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am kill ${event?.packageName}")
```