# Check status other app android

Tags: android

I am using this code to open one app from another:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.p2a");
    intent.putExtra("application_id", 2);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

How I can check if this another app is running? I want to If running- kill and start again, if no-start app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the app's running status through this

```
ActivityManager aManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfo = aManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < processInfo.size(); i++){
        if(processInfo.get(i).processName.equals("myPackage.myAppName")) {
            //Kill app
        }
    }
     //Start app
```

Comment: @user1302569, I haven't tried that yet. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12037227/1777090 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/4504690/1777090. That might help.